# How to wait until a function which contains an AJAX request is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried something like this :

```
// ...
SaveSomething: function () {
    var item1 = "" //something;
    MyTools.Ajax("SaveSomething", {
        item: item1
    }).done(function (res) {
        return res.list;
    });
},
// ...
```

And there is the function that calls this `SaveSomething` function (part of a singleton)

```
// This is not working at all...
function SaveSomethingProcess() {
    $.when(MyObject.SaveSomething()).done(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

I want to be able from somewhere else to call `var k = SaveSomethingProcess();`, wait the inner's AJAX call `SaveSomething` to be done and take the res object to the `k` variable.

Is it possible with promises or something?

Comment: You can't do that I'm afraid. However you could return the promise from `MyObject.SaveSomething` then use `done()` on that promise. Alternatively you could follow your current pattern and change `SaveSomethingProcess()` to take a callback function which you pass along to `done()`

Comment: Can you demonstrate the first solution you said?

Comment: You should specify **async**  attribute to _false_ and then check **responseText** attribute but it's deprecated, so you should review your process in order to use callback functions.

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola never, *ever* use `async: false`

Comment: @GiannisGrivas there's a great explanation of the problem and the workarounds in the duplicate question

Comment: thank you @RoryMcCrossan